# Use properties of the Bernoulli Polynomials to prove $\int_0^1 B_n(x)dx= 0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, bernoulli-polynomials

Use the properties of the Bernoulli Polynomials to prove:
$$\int_0^1 P_n(x)dx= 0 \tag{for n>0}$$

I have these properties to work with below:
$$P_0(x) = 1; \qquad P'_n(x) = n P_{n-1} (x) \qquad P_n (x+1) - P_n (x) = nx^{n-1}  $$

I don't have work to show because I am questioning what step one should be?  I believe I want to manipulate the derivative somehow so that the integral just undoes it, and end with the difference property, which is apart by 1 just like the bounds on the integral.  How can I show this?

Comment: Is $B_n(x) = P_n(x)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see the concise answer.  After a hint, I was able to construct a long-winded answer of my own:

$$P'_{n+1}(x)=(n+1)P_{n}(x)$$
$$P_{n}(x)= \frac{P'_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{P'_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}dx$$ 
$$P_{n+1} (x+1) - P_{n+1} (x) = \frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{(n+1)}$$
$$=x^n , ({x = 0})$$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You will have to proceed by induction on $n$. You can manipulate the second identity to obtain $$\int_0^1B_n(x)dx = \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1B_{n+1}'(x)dx,$$ which you can evaluate with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Can you handle it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$I_n=\int_0^1 B_{n-1}(x)dx=\frac1{n}\left[B_n(1)-B_n(0)\right]$$
Since $$B_n(x+1)-B_n(x)=nx^{n-1}$$
we evaluate at $x=0$:
$$I_n=\frac1n[n\cdot 0^{n-1}]=0$$
QED